# Get data from to tables with one to one relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, api, one-to-one

I'm working on my first Laravel project, and I want to create a REST Api with the framework to consume it with AngularJS. In my system, I have two types of users: **User A** and **User B**. I would like to use the default Laravel's users table to handle the authentication, and create another two tables, usera and userb, each one with a column **user_id** that is a foreign key to the users table.

I'll use only the usera table to explain my problem. My migrations are like it:

**The users table**

```
    //users table migration
        class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
        {
            public function up()
            {
                Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->increments('id');
                    $table->string('name');
                    $table->string('email')->unique();
                    $table->string('password');
                    $table->rememberToken();
                    $table->timestamps();
                });
            }
    ...
        }
```

**The usera table**

```
    class CreateUserA extends Migration
    {
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('usera', function(Blueprint $table){
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('document_number')
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
        ...
    }
```

In the UserA model class I did it:

```
class UserA extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('id', 'document_number', 'user_id');
    protected $hidden = array('created_at', 'updated_at');

    public function user(){
        $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

So, I created a UsersA controller to with the API methods, and configured the routes to access the corresponding function. The 'api/usersa/' url via GET is redirect to the index function of my controller, and the function is like that:

```
public function index($id = null) {
    if ($id == null) {
        return UserA::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    }else{
        return Usuario::find($id);
    }
}
```

With this, I can get the usersa table data, but I would like merge the users and usersa table, and get something like this as response:

```
[
   {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'foo',
      'email': 'foo@bar.com',
      'document_number': '1234'
   }
]
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be flat like that? The simplest solution is:

```
public function index($id = null) {
    if ($id == null) {
        return UserA::with('user')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    }else{
        return Usuario::with('usera')->find($id); // or whatever the relation name is.
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it before ask here, but it fires an Exception: `Call to undefined relationship [users] on model [App\\UserA].`

I thought that only creating the foreign key the framework will "understand" the relation. I need do something more?

Comment: the relation is `user` not `users`

Comment: yeah, you're right! Now worked. I had understand that there should be the name of the db table

Comment: the relation name is defined by you, in the code above `public function user(){`. Glad I could help!